# Pandas Only Writing First Row With New Value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a script that sets all the dates to the first day of the month, then finds the mode so I can overwrite any stragglers in a different month.

I have almost everything working, but for some reason when I go to overwrite the date column with the mode, it's only setting the first row with the new value and setting everything else to NaT.

```
arrange_df.loc[:, 'date'] = date_mode
```

I'm not sure why this is occurring. I have tried the following:

```
arrange_df['date'] = date_mode
```

And that still only sets the first value.

And even when I specify a segment - like [0:3] - it's still not setting everything in that segment.

In case you need it - here is the script:

```
arrange_df['date'] = arrange_df['date'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
pd.to_datetime(arrange_df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
date_mode = arrange_df['date'].mode()
arrange_df.loc[:, 'date'] = date_mode
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the shape of date_mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `arrange_df.loc[:,'date'] = date_mode.values` it will work because you are taking mode of data column and it will return series of a single value and you are trying to assign series of single index to whole column that's why its returning NaT after index 0.

Comment: Hi Bilal, Your answer would be greater by adding details why it solves the question, as if you were explaining to someone in front of you. Best

Comment: @BilalAhmed Thank you sooooo much! This worked, and I appreciate your explanation too.

Comment: @MadisonLeopold It's my pleasure.